# I can not login to mac book pro

Tags: macbook-pro, login-screen

When i turn on my MacBook and select user and then enter password , it does not accept my password, after 3 or 4 times entering password it works, i do know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very strange issue. However check for the default keyboard, and also try changing your password to just numbers. That way you can confirm if its something to do with the keyboard language.

However, its better to create a new user account and confirm. If you have the issue take it to an AppleStore or just try to reinstall the OS on top. That way it will fix if there are any issues due to a malware.

Comment: I made a new password without 'caps lock' , i checked it until now it works, my old password had one letter with 'on caps lock' , any way i did not understand what is the problem

Comment: Interesting. Hope you understand the difference between the capslock and the shift button. Try to use some numbers for login password. that would make things easy. Glad it worked.

Comment: I do not know different between capslock and shift button, you mean if i was using shift button instead of 'capslock on, my password was working.